market:// link for opening developer profile in Google Play Store app
On an Android device you can use market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps to open an app directly in the Google Play Store app without first visiting a browser.
Is there something like this for the developer profile as well?
Like e.g. this developer profile: https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=5700313618786177705

You can set a package in your intent to handle the link. In this case, you can set the Play Store package:
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
data = Uri.parse(
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=<developer_id>")
setPackage("com.android.vending")
}
startActivity(intent)

More information here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play
